# Can I use Poletergeist with Capybara to test negative presence of option in select

Tags: capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

If I have this html:

```
<select name"bo">
    <option value="yo">Yo</option>
    <option value="ho">Ho</option>
    <option value="go">Go</option>
</select>
```

What step definition can I use Capybara utilizing Poltergeist to get a failing test on this step:

```
Then Select "bo" does not contain the "yo" option
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your question.  You could do something like this:

```
it "doesn't find element" do
  visit whatever_path
  expect { select "NotARealOption", from: "bo" }.to raise_error(SomeCapybaraError, "no match found")
end
```

Comment: Interesting, I'd never seen the use of raise_error. I'll give that a try soon.

Comment: Worked with just a bit of tweaking for my setup:
`expect { select option, from: field }.to raise_error(Capybara::ElementNotFound)`